# Insert string into array - PAWN script

Tags: arrays, merge, string-concatenation, pawn

I am trying to cut down my file lines by having one variable to insert into several arrays. So I'd like to have a string, or an array variable, such as the following:

```
new combomeals[] = { 
    3025101, 3025100, 3003000, 3025002, 3030101, 3025001, 3025000, 3021602, 3031402, 3020100, 
    3031401, 3031400, 3031302, 3020242, 3031301, 3031300, 3021702, 3021701, 3021700, 3020602, 
    3021601, 3030100, 3021600, 3021502, 3021501, 3020201, 3021500, 3020150, 3020502, 3020501, 
    3020500, 3001802, 3001801, 3001800, 3001702, 3001701, 3001700, 3011602, 3011601, 3011600, 
    3011502, 3020202, 3011501, 3011500, 3011232, 3011231, 3011202, 3011201, 3010602, 3010601, 
    3010600, 3010902, 3010901, 3010900, 3011102, 3011101, 3011100, 3011002, 3011001, 3011000, 
}
```

It's actually much longer than that, but I shortened it for the explanation... I want to take combomeals[] and put that into other arrays. The following does not work, but you will get the idea:

```
new first_array[] = { 
    1, 
    2, 
    3,
    combomeals[], 
}

new second_array[] = { 
    4, 
    5, 
    6,
    combomeals[], 
}

new third_array[] = { 
    7, 
    8, 
    9,
    combomeals[], 
}
```

The end goal is to put the first array into several other arrays. Please let me know if this makes sense and if you are able to help!

Thank you!

Comment: What specific part are you having problems with?

Comment: Putting combomeals[] into other arrays. I want first_array[] to print 1, 2, 3, 3025101, 3025100, 3003000, 3025002, 3030101, 3025001, 3025000, 3021602, 3031402, 3020100, 3031401, 3031400, 3031302, 3020242, 3031301, 3031300, 3021702,  etc, etc ,etc... Right now I get a syntax error.

Comment: I suggest you fix the error.

Comment: ... I am actually wondering HOW to do this? The error I get is because I am not sure how to do this sort of thing in a pawn script. I am really trying to do something like this: char str1[100] = "Hello,"; strcat(str1, " world!"); to get "Hello world!"... Do you understand?

Comment: Error is: invalid expression, assumed zero

Comment: Did you really do `typedef int new`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot extend an array in the way you are attempting. Assuming that `new` has been aliased to an integral type, then the compiler will only accept the initializer list for `first_array` if all the elements in the list are the same type. But the last element of the list is a syntactic error, as `combomeals` is an array, and `combomeals[]` doesn't belong in an initializer list.

Similarly for the `second_array` and `third_array`.

You can accomplish something similar by putting the numbers in `combomeals` into a macro instead:

```
#define COMBOS \
3025101, 3025100, 3003000, 3025002, 3030101, 3025001, 3025000, 3021602, 3031402, 3020100, \
3031401, 3031400, 3031302, 3020242, 3031301, 3031300, 3021702, 3021701, 3021700, 3020602, \
3021601, 3030100, 3021600, 3021502, 3021501, 3020201, 3021500, 3020150, 3020502, 3020501, \
3020500, 3001802, 3001801, 3001800, 3001702, 3001701, 3001700, 3011602, 3011601, 3011600, \
3011502, 3020202, 3011501, 3011500, 3011232, 3011231, 3011202, 3011201, 3010602, 3010601, \
3010600, 3010902, 3010901, 3010900, 3011102, 3011101, 3011100, 3011002, 3011001, 3011000,

new combomeals[] = { COMBOS };

new first_array[] = { 1, 2, 3, COMBOS };
new second_array[] = { 4, 5, 6, COMBOS };
new third_array[] = { 7, 8, 9, COMBOS };
```

---

If your compiler has trouble dealing with a long source line, you may have to split `COMBOS` apart. It is less convenient, but a `c89` compiler is only required to support a source file length 509 bytes long.

```
#define COMBOS1 \
3025101, 3025100, 3003000, 3025002, 3030101, 3025001, 3025000, 3021602, 3031402, 3020100, \
3031401, 3031400, 3031302, 3020242, 3031301, 3031300, 3021702, 3021701, 3021700, 3020602, \
3021601, 3030100, 3021600, 3021502, 3021501, 3020201, 3021500, 3020150, 3020502, 3020501
#define COMBOS2 \
3020500, 3001802, 3001801, 3001800, 3001702, 3001701, 3001700, 3011602, 3011601, 3011600, \
3011502, 3020202, 3011501, 3011500, 3011232, 3011231, 3011202, 3011201, 3010602, 3010601, \
3010600, 3010902, 3010901, 3010900, 3011102, 3011101, 3011100, 3011002, 3011001, 3011000

new combomeals[] = {
    COMBOS1,
    COMBOS2,
};

new first_array[] = {
    1, 2, 3,
    COMBOS1,
    COMBOS2,
};

/* ...etc... */
```

You may need to further break down the lines if your C compiler is non-conforming.

Comment: I believe this will work... Thank you so much for understanding... Now I have another issue though -   6/14 16:42:55:: LOG - 20130614164255.000    |  TEST.p(166) : error 075: 
input line too long (after substitutions). I get that at least 20 times. I tried shortening the length of each row, but it makes no difference. Thoughts?

Comment: I limited each number to one line, still not working. 1, \ 2, \ 3, \

Comment: @Gonzo'sMemoirs: You have to split the line apart itself, not the macro. The macro just becomes one long line. See my updated answer.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean... I had it on 98 separate lines followed by "\" and this did not work... I tried with 196 lines and half the line characters, this did not work either. Perhaps I just don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Actually, I did something like what your modified edit was... but 98 times... It tried to load for a very long time, and never finished. I think this is a 'correct' answer, but I can't get it to run in my system (probably because this file is gigantic).

Comment: @Gonzo'sMemoirs: See my updated answer. You need to use two separate macros. One for the first half of the numbers. One for the second half of the numbers. When using the two macros, put one macro on one line, put the other macro on a separate line below it. You shouldn't need 98 of them. Try 2.

Comment: Completely got it working. You're a wizard! Harry... Thank you so much for the help. You just removed thousands of lines from my file.